# fullcalendar v3 month view multiple days event render start and end date half

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

It's my first post here so excuse me for being stupid :)

I have a fullcalendar v3 with multiple events (each event on multiple days).

In month view how can I customize the event start and end to be rendered as half of the day container width and the next event to start on the other half. Also all events to stay on same row.

Here's a picture with what I am looking for.

[image]

And my events array.

```
var events_array = [
    {
        title  : 'Event 1',
        start  : '2016-10-21T13:00:00',
        end : '2016-10-22T12:00:00'
    },
      {
        title  : 'Event 2',
        start  : '2016-10-22T13:00:00',
        end : '2016-10-24T12:00:00'
    },
      {
        title  : 'Event 3',
        start  : '2016-10-24T13:00:00',
        end : '2016-10-27T12:00:00'
    },
    {
        title  : 'Event 4',
        start  : '2016-10-27T13:00:00',
        end : '2016-11-12T12:00:00'
    }
    ];
```

Thanks